# Coordinates with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ = {{1,2},{2,3}}

Find a basis for the span of {$I_2$, $A$, $A^2$, $A^3$} in $M_{2×2}$. Find the coordinates for $A^{−1}$ with respect to your basis (All of {$I_2$, $A$, $A^2$, $A^3$})

I found the basis for $I_2$, $A$, $A^2$, and $A^3$. I am wondering what "Find the coordinates for $A^{−1}$ with respect to your basis" is asking for specifically and how I might set up the problem to make the calculations.

I am aware the formula for coordinates is $[x]_B$=$x$$P_B^{-1}$. So how would I set it up in this specific question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Suggestion\Hint:* If it is true that $A^{-1}$ is in the span of $\{I_2, A, A^2, A^3\}$ then you can find scalars $a, b, c, d$ such that
$$
\text{(1)}~~~~aI_2 + bA + c A^2 + dA^3 =A^{-1}
$$
These $(a,b,c,d)$ are the coordinates for $A^{-1}$ in this basis. Now, to find $a,b,c,d$ you should notice that for equation $(1)$ to be true, then each component of the resulting matrix on the left side of the equality must equal the components of $A^{-1}$. This will lead you to $4$ equations with $4$ unknowns which should have (at least) one solution if $A^{-1}$ is in the span.